# Inner syntax error when using `o` as a variable/function name

Tags: isabelle

While playing around with Isabelle (version 2016-1), I encountered the following strange situation: I cannot use the letter `o` as a variable or function name in various (most/all?) contexts. The following examples all fail despite working for most (all?) other letters of the English alphabet:

```
value o (* quoted version doesn't work either *)

definition invert :: ‹bool ⇒ bool› where
  ‹invert o = (¬ o)›

definition o :: ‹bool ⇒ bool› where
  ‹o a = (¬ a)›

fun default_int :: ‹int option ⇒ int› where
  ‹default_int None = 0› |
  ‹default_int o = the o›

fun default_int :: ‹int option ⇒ int› where
  ‹default_int None = 0› |
  ‹default_int (Some o) = o›

fun o :: ‹int option ⇒ int› where
  ‹o None = 0› |
  ‹o (Some i) = i›
```

I cannot seem to find any information documenting `o` being a reserved name, so is this a bug or is there some other usage of `o` that precludes it as a variable/function name? The error message for all cases is "Inner syntax error⌂ Failed to parse term", which is not very helpful other than noting that the error seems to be inner-syntax-related (the error messages for the third and last cases appear on the lines using `o` inside quotes rather than on the definition/fun lines, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`o` is the ASCII notation for the function composition operator `∘`. You can see that the `o` is interpreted as syntax because it is printed in a kind of dark turquoise colour, whereas other identifiers are blue, black, green, or orange (depending on what they are precisely). You get the same thing with other pre-defined syntax like `O`, `OO`, `powr`, `has_derivative`, etc.

You can disable that for your purposes using the command

```
no_notation Fun.comp (infixl "o" 55)
```

You should, however, only do this for experimentation; in production use, it would be considered bad to disable such a global pre-defined notation.

I for one think that these days, these old ASCII notations are mostly unnecessary and, in case of `o`, actually harmful (e.g. how it confused you). I'll suggest removing this particular notation on the Isabelle mailing list.

Comment: Well that makes some sense. `value ‹f o g›` and `value ‹f ∘ g›` do indeed produce the same result, and with a valid term ctrl-clicking the `o` does go to the definition of `Fun.comp`.

Comment: fyi I brought up the matter on the mailing list and the consensus seems to be that we want to remove the `o` notation – however, the matter is complicated a bit by the related `O` and `OO` notations for relational composition. They do not have non-ASCII notation and it is not obvious what one could replace the ASCII notation with.

Comment: I'm guessing that there are some limitations/ambiguities that prevent ∘ from being overloaded to be both `o` and `O` due to how they impose a type restriction on their parameters? (Using `OO` as another identifier seems like an even unlikelier case than using `o` or `O`, though.)